# What was the name of the typeface used on the Mac OS 9/OS X Cheeta/Jaguar packaging?

Tags: font, classic-mac-os, panther

I am curious as to what typeface was used on the Mac OS 9 & early Mac OS X boxes. Where it reads "Installing Mac OS 9". The slopes of the letters are slightly different than any font that comes pre-installed on a modern Mac, and the *9* is obviously quite unique looking. If anyone is aware of the typeface name please let me know. Danke. [image: Mac OS 9 logo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font being used is Apple Garamond. This was used by Apple as one of its corporate fonts since the Mac was first launched in 1984 up until the early 2000s.

For more information on this and other typefaces used by Apple, refer to [Typography of Apple Inc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typography_of_Apple_Inc.).

Comment: After some research I have discovered claims that this font can be extracted from the Setup Assistant.app on several versions of OS X, though after going through my install disks for 9.1-10.3 I could find no such thing. Are you aware as to whether or not it can actually be obtained from the installer?

Comment: I'm aware of those claims, but to be honest I've never actually tried it. I do have all the original macOS install disks going back 25+ years, so I can have a go at it myself, although I wouldn't get a chance until the weekend. There was also an Apple Font Pack (or something like that) which I have somewhere - but I don't recall if Apple Garamond was included or not. Can I ask how you're wanting to use it? That may have an impact on what version you'll need. Also, you can actually download non-official versions of Apple Garamond which are pretty close, if that's of any use to you.

Comment: I recently purchased a new copy of the OS 9.1 CD (I sold my old one quite a while back, thinking I wouldn't need it.), but it came in a paper sleeve with no box or case. The disc was in perfect condition however, so I want to make a cover for the jewel case I'm keeping it in. I want it to look as authentic as possible for my own peace of mind, as of right now its just sitting in a generic unmarked case, and it's bothering me every time I look at it. A disc this well preserved deserves proper packaging, in my opinion.

Comment: I've tried several of the unofficial versions already, but the accents and slopes are too different from the original as far as I'm concerned. When you put the two side by side the difference it pretty clear, even if the individual differences are small, there are so many of them that most unofficial versions just look like regular Garamond to me, and those that are closer to Apple's version are so slightly off that it creates an uncanny valley effect, for lack of a better phrase.

Comment: No worries. :) What software and version of macOS are you wanting to use the font in?

Comment: GIMP 2.8, on Sierra

Comment: Houston, we have a problem. I spent a couple of hours today scouring through some old macOS install media (from Mac OS 7 up to Mac OS X 10.3) and collected a whole heap of fonts, placed them on a USB flash drive, and then packed everything away (including the old Power Macs I was using). I then plugged the USB into my main Mac and none of the fonts are visible. I then tested the USB on all the Macs I have *easy* access to (ranging from Snow Leopard to Sierra) and none of them can see the fonts. So I'm thinking this isn't going to work for you in Sierra. :(

Comment: I figure we have three options: (1) Forget the font and instead increase the resolution of the image you have and crop the text out of it for your project; (2) I grab the old Power Mac out of storage and create both a disk image and an archive of the fonts and hope this somehow works on newer systems; or (3) I go digging around for the old Apple Fonts Pack and see if this works on Sierra. Alternatively, if you have another suggestion, I'm all ears. :)

Comment: I suppose it could work without the text, though I would prefer it look as much like the original box as possible, albeit cropped to fit in a jewel case. I appreciate that you spent that much time looking already, and don't want to ask you to go digging through storage again. Plus I was also unable to see the fonts while browsing my copies of the discs (also on Sierra), so making a disk image likely wont help. You'd think it would be easier to find a picture of the OS 9 cover, but all the image searches I've done have turned up nothing. Perhaps I'll have to use  a 3rd party font.

Comment: I had found (aside from the picture above) a single straight-on picture of the Mac OS 9 installer box, but like I said I'm making a cover for 9.1, which is why I needed the font.